# Shellscript If statement returns error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to check if a file is older than 5 minutes and if that is the case I want to call another shell script which sends me a mail.

check_file.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [$(( (`date +%s` - `stat -L --format %Y /home/ftp/test.txt`) > (5*60) ))] = 1
        then sh ./testmail.sh
fi
```

Error output:  3: ./check_file.sh: [1]: not found

Comment: Add spaces in your if condition: `if [ condition ]`, not `if [condition]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if find /home/ftp/test.txt -mmin +5 &>/dev/null; then
    <your code>
fi
```

Comment: That way the "then" statemant will always be executed... just tried it.

Comment: That's just a hint. Anyway the find program is the best way to check those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
if test "`find /home/ftp/test.txt -mmin +5`"; then
        echo "file found"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script first calculates a number, by virtue of the `$((....))` expression. In your case, this number seems to be `1`.

This means that you are left with the command

```
if [1] = 1
```

This means that bash tries to find a command named `[1]` and invoke it with two parameters, `=` and `1`.

Since no executable file named `[1]` is found in your PATH, bash tells you that it can not find the file.

I think

```
if (( (`date +%s` - `stat -L --format %Y /home/ftp/test.txt`) == 1 ))
then 
    ....
```

should do the job.